# Craft 3 Template - Getting Image URLs

Tags: templating, craft3

I am having a problem getting image urls from Craft 3. I understand that there is a new syntax but I cannot find the syntax to use. The craft 2 version of what I am trying to accomplish is

```
{% set heroImage = entry.heroImage.first().url %}
```

How do I achieve this in Craft 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
{% set heroImage = entry.heroImage.one().getUrl() %}
```

Although this probably works as well:

```
{% set heroImage = entry.heroImage.one().url %}
```

In Craft 3, `.first()` has been replaced with `.one()`.  https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/changes-in-craft-3.html#query-methods